# How avoid first argument must be a string or Buffer node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to put an html in a page in node.js and this is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs=require('fs');

fs.readFile('C:\Users\Eventi\Desktop\Node.js\Progetti\ProveNodeJS\NodeJSProve\home.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {

    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
});
```

When I go at the url `http://localhost:8000` I obtain the error  `first argument must be a string or Buffer node js` . Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your `readFile()` failed and `err` is set (`html` is probably `undefined`). You should fill in your `if (err) {}` block to do something useful when this is the case.

Also, the most likely reason for the error is that the backslashes are not escaped in your literal filename string. So instead you'll need:

```
'C:\\Users\\Eventi\\Desktop\\Node.js\\Progetti\\ProveNodeJS\\NodeJSProve\\home.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape your path:

```
fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\Eventi\\Desktop\\Node.js\\Progetti\\ProveNodeJS\\NodeJSProve\\home.html', function (err, html) {
```

And try again.